# ERROR in ./src/main.js Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): SyntaxError: : Unexpected reserved word 'let' (12:4)

Tags: javascript, dictionary, babeljs

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks!

ERROR in ./src/map.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/elodie/Desktop/P7_Moret_elodie/src/map.js: Unexpected reserved word 'let' (12:4)

map.js

```js
let map, infoWindow;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.483333, 3.283333),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

}
if (navigator.geolocation)
    let watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(successCallback,
        null, {
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        });
else
    alert("Votre navigateur ne prend pas en compte la géolocalisation HTML5");

function successCallback(position) {
    map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
        map: map
    });
}

export {
    initMap
};
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "p7_moret_elodie",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --watch --mode='development'",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    watch: true,
    entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./src/index.js"],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: "bundle.js",
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        open: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Have been trying to figure out what wrong with my setup or code, trying to do redux main website map examples but there is error on the provider in the index.js file?
ERROR

```js
bundle.js:20869 Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/elodie/Desktop/P7_Moret_elodie/src/map.js: Unexpected reserved word 'let' (12:4)

[0m [90m 10 | [39m}[0m
[0m [90m 11 | [39m[36mif[39m (navigator[33m.[39mgeolocation)[0m
[0m[31m[1m>[22m[39m[90m 12 | [39m    let watchId [33m=[39m navigator[33m.[39mgeolocation[33m.[39mwatchPosition(successCallback[33m,[39m[0m
[0m [90m    | [39m    [31m[1m^[22m[39m[0m
[0m [90m 13 | [39m        [36mnull[39m[33m,[39m {[0m
[0m [90m 14 | [39m            enableHighAccuracy[33m:[39m [36mtrue[39m[0m
[0m [90m 15 | [39m        })[33m;[39m[0m
    at Parser._raise (:8081/Users/elodie/Desktop/P7_Moret_elodie/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:742)
    at Parser.raiseWithData (:8081/Users/elodie/Desktop/P7_Moret_elodie/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:735)
    at Parser.raise (:8081/Users/elodie/Desktop/P7_Moret_elodie/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:729)
    at Parser.checkReservedWord (:8081/Users/elodie/Desktop/P7_Moret_elodie/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10817)
    at Parser.parseIdentifierName (:8081/Users/elodie/Desktop/P7_Moret_elodie/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10777)
    at Parser.parseIdentifier (:8081/Users/elodie/Desktop/P7_Moret_elodie/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10748)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (:8081/Users/elodie/Desktop/P7_Moret_elodie/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9888)
    at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (:8081/Users/elodie/Desktop/P7_Moret_elodie/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9624)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (:8081/Users/elodie/Desktop/P7_Moret_elodie/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9604)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (:8081/Users/elodie/Desktop/P7_Moret_elodie/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9474)
    at Object../src/map.js (bundle.js:20869)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.0 (bundle.js:20882)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
```

Comment: You can't declare a variable in a "single-statement context" (In your example an if-statement without brackets). What is the goal of `watchId`?

Comment: Note that it also applies to `marker` in your `successCallback` function as you (apparently) do nothing with it - I don't think it will throw an error though